# Getting a picture to display on top of a button with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to put an `ImageView` and `TextView` over (on top) of a button using the new `ConstraintLayout` in Android Studios. Below is what I currently use for my app but *RelativeLayouts* are very time consuming for making a layout for every device size.

[image: News feed picture]

This is my XML

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newfeedbtn"
            android:background="@drawable/newsfeedbtn"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/NFRedC"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:background="@drawable/alert"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/NFTextNumber"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Does anyone know a way where I can do this using constraints? or is there a way to specify the order in which pictures are display without using a layout inside a layout? *e.g. Microsoft office's "Send to back"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"is there a way to specify the order in which pictures are display without using a layout inside a layout?"

That's what FrameLayout does automatically.  It renders back-to-front, I.e. it draws the children in sequential order.  The first child is drawn first, the second on top of that, and the third on top of that.

Why not just do something like the following, similar to what you already have, but without the redundant FrameLayout that currently contains the button?

```
<FrameLayout...>
    <Button/>
    <TextView/>
    <ImageView/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Does this make sense or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I will try that, last time I did the image wouldn't display over the button without putting it inside a framelayout. Will post update on results.

Comment: I played around with it for a few hours and without a "redundant FrameLayout" it doesn't work, no matter the order of objects (btn, tv, iv). The ImageView and TextView will never show otherwise. Should I use `src=""` instead of `background=""` or maybe an image button?

Comment: Alright you have to change the `Button` to `ImageButton` and it'll work